# Elastic Search with phonetic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-phonetic

Im trying to get Elastic Search making a phonetic search in a list of cities. My goal is to find matching results even if the user uses an incorrect spelling.

I've done the following steps:

1. Remove domain

   ```
   curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/city/"
   ```
2. Create new domain

   ```
   curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/city/?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'                                                      
   {
     "settings": {
       "index": {
         "analysis": {
           "analyzer": {
             "my_analyzer": {
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                 "lowercase",
                 "my_metaphone"
               ]
             }
           },
           "filter": {
             "my_metaphone": {
               "type": "phonetic",
               "encoder": "metaphone",
               "replace": true
             }
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "mappings": {
       "properties": {
         "name": {
           "type": "text",
           "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
         }
       }
     }
   }'
   ```
3. Fill some sample data

   ```
   curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/city/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
      "name":"Mayrhofen"
   }
   '

   curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/city/_doc/2?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
      "name":"Ischgl"
   }
   '

   curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/city/_doc/3?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
      "name":"Saalbach"
   }
   '
   ```
4. Search in the cities - here I get an result

   ```
   curl -X GET ""localhost:9200/city/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
      "query":{
         "query_string":{
            "query":"Mayrhofen" 
         }
      }
   }
   '
   ```

I tried the query with **Mayerhofen** and expected the same result as using **Mayrhofen**. The same issue with **Ischgl** and **Ichgl** or **Saalbach** and **Salbach**.

Where's my error? Is something mssing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are using wrong `encoder`. `metaphone` cannot match those.

What you need to use is `double_metaphone` for your inputs. It's based on phonetic algorithm implementation. I would suggest you to understand your data and algorithm to ensure whether the phonetic algorithm is best fit for your purpose.

Mapping:

```
{
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "double_meta_true_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "true_doublemetaphone"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "true_doublemetaphone": {
            "type": "phonetic",
            "encoder": "double_metaphone",
            "replace": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

It matches the docs.

**Why metaphone is not matching:**

```
GET http://localhost:9200/city2/_analyze
{
   "field":"meta_true",
   "text":"Mayrhofen"
}
```

yields

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "MRHF",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

And analysing below

```
{
   "field":"meta_true",
   "text":"Mayerhofen"
}
```

yields

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "MYRH",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Double_Metaphone works the below way:**

```
GET
{
   "field":"doublemeta_true",
   "text":"Mayerhofen"
}
```

And

```
{
   "field":"doublemeta_true",
   "text":"Mayerhofen"
}
```

and

```
{
   "field":"doublemeta_true",
   "text":"Mayrhofen"
}
```

yields

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "MRFN",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... stupidly every example I found using phoentic search was using `metaphone` encoder.

Comment: Hi @Gibbs: Is there a way to get the "correct" search phrase, like google does: "Did you mean: mayrhofen" when I look for "Maierhofen"?

Comment: You need to use phrase `suggester` and handle it in your code.

Comment: Are there any special installations or configurations needed?